The remote read zone cannot obtain table information
I have built a CnosDB monitoring environment here: CnosDB+Grafana+Prometheus.
I learned that monitoring is implemented because CnosDB implements remote reading and writing of Prometheus.
I created a table in the CnosDB environment and wrote the data as follows
CREATE TABLE air (visibility DOUBLE,temperature DOUBLE,pressure DOUBLE,TAGS(station));
INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, pressure) VALUES (1667456411000000000, 'XiaoMaiDao1', 56, 69, 411);

But when I query this table in Grafana, I find that it cannot be queried.(The data I obtained through monitoring can be queried and displayed visually in Grafana. And the data I write through CnosDB and the monitoring data are in the same database)
Does anyone know what is the reason for this? Can you help me with suggestions for modifications?
